# Disabling Lock Aspect Ratio VBA - Excel

Tags: vba, excel, aspect-ratio

I've read a few forums but none of them seem to be working for me.

I'm pulling pictures from the web, and inserting them into my spreadsheet. I'd like all of these pictures to have the same dimension.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim img_url as string, picture as object
img_url = Range("A1")    'Some url with an img

With ActiveSheet.Pictures
   Set Picture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(img_url)
   Picture.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
   Picture.Width = 25
   PictureHeight = 25
End With
```

Every time I run it, the Lock Aspect Ratio setting is still checked, and the image is not in the square format I'm looking for.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Should `PictureHeight` be `Picture.Height`? Also, the `With` block appears to be redundant.

Comment: the `LockAspectRatio = msoFalse` is a member of the `Shape` object library

Comment: @marldog  see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below, the `LockAspectRatio` attribute is a property of the `Picture.ShapeRange` object, and not the `Picture`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImageAttributes()

Dim img_url As String
Dim picture As Object

img_url = Range("A1")    'Some url with an img

With ActiveSheet
   Set picture = .Pictures.Insert(img_url)
   With picture
        With .ShapeRange
          .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
          .Width = 25
          .Height = 25
        End With
   End With
End With


End Sub
```